# Unable to brew install mongodb on mac os 10.12

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I can't find any solution on the Google.

wanglangdeMacBook-Pro:Cellar wanglang$ brew install mongodb

Error: mongodb: unknown version :mountain_lion

Thx!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your machine is toooooooo old ;)

[Homebrew only support the latest version of macOS (macOS 10.12 Mojave) and support the previous 3 generation (macOS 10.9-10.11) on a "best-effort" basis.](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#2)

My recommendation is that you should upgrade your machine to the latest macOS Mojave.

Comment: Thx! But actually the version of my mac is 10.12.6 Sierra, I don't know why it told me  the version is mountain_lion... So is it still necessary to update? I'm kinda afraid of some unknown issues...

Comment: Sorry. Can you check if `brew update` and then `brew install mongodb` will solve your issue?

Comment: Problem solved! THANKS!

Comment: @W.lang how did you solve it, because I am facing the same issue. Brew is up to date but I get the same error.

Comment: @DavidEssien What version of macOS are you using? and what is your `brew update` output? Also try run `brew doctor`.