# Error: MongoDB: unknown version: mountain_lion

Tags: mongodb, macos, command-line, server

I am running these simple commands on mac:

```
brew upgrade mongodb
```

or

```
brew install mongodb
```

I am getting this error below:

> Error: mongodb: unknown version :mountain_lion

If I run the simple command: mongo , I get this,

> MongoDB shell version v4.0.3

But then I get an error saying couldn't connect to server

Worth to note, I was playing around with the command line last night and somehow deleted all of my databases from mongodb on my machine (I think). I continuously get the above error when trying install and/or update mongodb.

I am "new" to mongoDB, but I have created a few full stack projects using it over the last 5-6 months. Not sure what I did, but I also can't run node db/seeds.js either as I get errors, even though I have the data in my vscode projects.

I've tried simply updating and installing mongodb. I also tried some simple server commands but was unsuccessful.

Comment: What version of OS X are you using? Is it actually Mountain Lion (10.8.x)?

Comment: @Stennie I am running macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6.. problem is still not solved as when I run mongo commands it gives me the error of.. Error: mongodb: unknown version :mountain_lion

Comment: Try following the instructions to [Install MongoDB 4.0 using the Homebrew Tap](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/). I'm not sure why you're getting the error message about `mountain_lion`, but the official Tap is a different formula from the one you are trying to install. Hopefully your missing data files are still present in the default Homebrew path of `/usr/local/var/mongodb` and will be used when you are able to successfully install and start the MongoDB server using `brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and clarity @Stennie !

Comment: @TrayFleary have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 34):

It seems the mongodb tap was moved. This worked for me:

- `brew uninstall mongodb`
- From https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew

  - `brew tap mongodb/brew`
  - `brew install mongodb-community`

Comment: I saw the original error when I ran `brew doctor`. After following this solution, I now get `Your system is ready to brew.`

Answer (score 26):

Unfortunately, MongoDB has been [removed from homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/43770).

But... MongoDB team maintains a custom Homebrew tap.

I've uninstalled the old MongoDB:

```
brew services stop mongodb

brew uninstall mongodb
```

and reinstalled the new tap:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew

brew install mongodb-community

brew services start mongodb-community
```

Source: [mongobd/homebrew-brew Readme.md](https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew#starting-the-mongodb-community-server)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your system may be too old. Apparently mongo doesn't support older Mac systems - below 10.12 for community edition and 10.11 for enterprise.

Check this: [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900608/unable-to-brew-install-mongodb-on-mac-os-10-12)
and the [supported systems page on the mongo site](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/)

Comment: I am confused because my system says that I am running macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6.

Comment: Good to hear you solved it. Was it related to an older OS version or was the message a red herring?

Comment: It was definitely misleading. My version was updated to High Sierra at the time. I found that it was a problem with how I was using mongoDB, as homebrew recently removed it from core formulas and is maintaining a homebrew tap. As far as mountain lion, I am still not sure why my command line stated that this is what I was running.